# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $ (Different output each time)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, cordova

In my phonegap application there are various .js files. on click of footer menu I open other html file as

```
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="MainMenu.html" >Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="../../index.html" >Logout</a></li>

            </ul> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now suppose I click on Menu then it opens MainMenu.html file. But many times it show only black screen, some times it open MainMenu.html properly and sometimes it shows white screen and error messages like

```
07-02 11:52:54.172: E/Web Console(2292): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $ at file:///android_asset/www/UI/Equity/home.html#:52
```

Every time different responses are come why is it so?  This issue occurs in other cases also means when I click on suppose some button then sometimes it call nect html page but sometimes only blackscreen occurs and application hangs.

Comment: can you put full source of both the files?? it would be easy to track the errors then. you can put the source in `gist.github.com` if it is lengthy.

Comment: Your file paths might be wrong. Since both `MainMenu.html` and `index.html` are being referenced with relative paths, depending on the location of the page where this footer is, it may be right or wrong. This might be the reason that it works sometimes but not others

Comment: @ dhaval [link](https://gist.github.com/3031858) here is my 2 files home.html and MainMenu.html

Comment: @ Jayraj My file where Footer is placed and MainMenu.html are both in same package

Comment: Hi, When I run my application on 2.1 then there is no issue. But when I run it on 2.2 or 2.3 issue occurs why is it so? And one more thing when I ran it on 4.3 then sometimes application crashes.